# HasKey: error while using Fluent API to configure which property should be used as the foreign key

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have two classes (Parent, Child) in ASP.Net Core and I'm using code first approach, my real project is more complex than that, so i have to use this method to migrate to database.

The issue here is when I'm defining the relations in Db Context class i face this error noting that I'm following this Microsoft document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships, and you can find the main class below:

```
Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<logintest.Models.Chlid>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<logintest.Models.Child>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)


    public class Parent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Chlid> Childs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }

        public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Child> Childs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Parent)
                .WithMany(b => b.Childs)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.ParentId);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there a typo in the class name `Chlid`? or it should read `Child`.
After correcting the class name, the code has no error.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but it didn't appear other than the spelling problem in the model.

Comment: If your problem persists,I suggest you try adding a ForeignKey using Data Annotations, like this `[ForeignKey("ParentId")]`. You can refer to [this link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx).

Comment: @Neverever Yes it was really the issue, there was a mistake in class name in this line of code `public List<Chlid> Childs { get; set; }`

Comment: @Chen dear, i can't use this method in my real application because the relations between tables are more complex than this example and i should use (Has Key) when there are many foreign keys.